# Are limits of functions different in the complex plane

Tags: calculus, limits, metric-spaces, self-learning

I recently learnt about complex numbers and this got me thinking about the limits of functions for example when we say that $\lim\limits_{x \to 4} x^2=16$ we assume that $x^2$ is a function defined for all real numbers and we consider the limit as $x$ approaches $4$ from any direction within the domain of $x^2$ .however why don't we consider the limit as $x$ approaches $4$ from the complex numbers is it because $x^2$ is not defined for complex numbers?

Comment: It is the same for complex numbers. You can still apply $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit, since you have $||$ defined in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Usually when we talk about limits there is some underlying space. In this case the function $f(z) = z^2$ makes sense in both the reals & complex numbers and the limit is the same.

Comment: Good question. The reality is that the notation $x\to y$ is dependent on the domain of $x$ (which depends on what set we've been working in, so context dependent). In particular, we consider increasingly small open neighborhoods of $y$ with $y$ removed, and consider the value of the function on these neighborhoods. $x^2$ is continuous on both the reals and the complex numbers, so the limit is defined for both and is the same.

Comment: But for example the $\lim\limits_{x  \to 0} x^x$ is different for each x approaching from the complex plane and real plane

Answer (score 0):

You can think of convergence in $\mathbb C$ as convergence in $\mathbb R^2$ (they have the same topology). So if you take $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)$ where $f(z)$ is a complex function and $a$ is real and this limit exists, then it doesent matter how you aproach $a$ it will have the same limit so if you take the restriction of $f$ to the real line, namely $g=f|_{\mathbb R}$ then $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ where the second limit is on the real line.